# отличия operator new и expression new

Tags: c++

В чем разница между operator new и expression new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В том, что это совершенно разные, хоть и взаимосвязанные, вещи.

New-expression - это встроенная конструкция языка, при помощи которой в языке С++ создаются объекты в динамической памяти. Например

```
int *p1 = new int();
SomeClass *p2 = new SomeClass[20];
```

А `operator new` (и `operator new[]`) - это функции выделения "сырой" неинициализированной памяти, которые неявно вызываются изнутри new-expression. 
В упрощенной форме алгоритм работы new-expression состоит из двух этапов:

1. Вызвать функцию выделения "сырой" памяти `operator new`/`operator new[]`
2. Проинициализировать (если необходимо) полученную от `operator new` "сырую" память - например, путем вызова конструктора(-ов) создаваемого объекта(-ов).

Стандартная библиотека предоставляет некую "базовую" реализацию функций `operator new`. Эти функции, при необходимости, также являются замещаемыми/перегружаемыми пользователем, в том числе индивидуально для каждого пользовательского класса.