# Использование "new []" вместо "new" в С++

Tags: c++, память

Можно ли использовать `new []` вместо `new`? К примеру:

```
int main()
{
    int q = 1;
    int *mass = new int [q];
    ...
    delete [] mass;
}
```

Спрашиваю потому, что хочется сделать код более универсальным, чтобы каждый раз не делать проверки на значения переменной `q`, где она может быть больше единицы или равной ей.
Будет ли такой код корректно функционировать? И не будет ли такой стиль считаться дурным тоном?

Comment: Э... а что мешает так делать?

Comment: Собственно говоря, поэтому и спрашиваю: нет ли никаких подводных камней при таком оформлении.

Comment: Хотите сделать код более универсальным - используйте стандартные контейнеры (std::vector<>,...), а не извращайтесь с использованием сырых new/delete. + прочитайте ответ к похожему вопросу - 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678966/отличия-operator-new-и-expression-new .

Comment: Да, это корректно. Нет, ничего дурного нет, подразумевая, что в теле есть какое-то изменение указателя `mass` или `q`, а это не просто написано из прихоти. Если код буквально так начинается, то можно добавить комментарий, дабы избежать разночтения. С другой стороны, в 9 случаях из 10 стоит использовать полноценный контейнер).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я мог бы использовать контейнеры, но задание не позволяет.

Comment: Тема вопроса "Можно ли использовать new [] вместо new?". О какой тогда проверке значения `q` идет речь? В варианте с new не было бы никакого `q`.

Answer (score 5):

Такой способ создания одиночных объектов непригоден в случаях, когда необходимо полиморфное удаление полиморфных объектов. Полиморфное удаление возможно только через `new`/`delete`, но не через `new[]`/`delete[]`.

Также такой способ создания одиночных объектов приведет к повышенному расходу памяти в случаях, когда объект имеет нетривиальный деструктор.

Comment: А что не так с полиморфным удалением через `delete[]`?

Comment: @alexolut если размер статического типа не равен размеру динамического, то при проходе такого массива не будем попадать в элементы уже начиная со второго. То есть если в памяти лежат объекты размером 8 байт, а указатель на тип размером 4 байта, то шагать delete[] будет по 4 байта, а не по 8 со всеми вытекающими.

Comment: @Croessmah ах, в этом плане, ну да ... сам же где-то недавно писал об этом :)

Comment: @alexolut: "Не так" в первую очередь то, что стандарт открытым текстом говорит, что попытка такого удаления приводит к неопределенному поведению. Размер массива значения не имеет. Обычный компилятор С++ не станет даже пытаться реализовывать полиморфное удаление в `delete []` - он просто вызовет впрямую деструктор базового класса и все.

Comment: @AnT обычный, получается, только clang. GCC и MSVC удалили по иерархии.

Comment: @alexolut: C MSVC понятно - они давным-давно упорно поддерживают полиморфное удаление массивов. Причем MSVC даже генерирует специальный виртуальный "векторный" деструктор, который знает правильный размер элемента массива (!), Т.е. в MSVC видна целенаправленная поддержка этой возможности в качестве расширения. Там все будет работать даже для массивов большего размера. А вот в GCC о размере элемента не беспокоятся, но деструктор все равно вызывают виртуальный. Скорее всего в GCC это просто случайный "хвост". Странно, ведь в общем случае это делает код менее оптимальным.

Answer (score 4):

Никто не мешает писать `new T[n]`, где `n == 1`.

Однако само по себе использование `new T[n]` и `new T` считается дурным тоном, т.к. есть `std::vector<T>` и `std::make_unique<T>`.

В частности С++ Core Guidelines не рекомендуют использование "naked new":

> [ES.60: Avoid new and delete outside resource management functions](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es60-avoid-new-and-delete-outside-resource-management-functions)
>
> Reason
> Direct resource management in application code is error-prone and tedious.